# How to aggregate data by period in a rrdtool graph

Tags: linux, rrdtool

I have a rrd file with average ping times to a server (GAUGE) every minute and when the server is offline (which is very frequent for reasons that doesn't matter now) it stores a NaN/unknown.

I'd like to create a graph with the percentage the server is offline each hour which I think can be achieved by counting every NaN within 60 samples and then dividing by 60.

For now I get to the point where I define a variable that is 1 when the server is offline and 0 otherwise, but I already read the docs and don't know how to aggregate this:

```
DEF:avg=server.rrd:rtt:AVERAGE CDEF:offline=avg,UN,1,0,IF
```

Is it possible to do this when creating a graph? Or I will have to store that info in another rrd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want, but you have a couple of options.

You can define a *sliding window average*, that shows the percentage of the previous hour that was unknown, and graph that, using `TRENDNAN`.

```
DEF:avg=server.rrd:rtt:AVERAGE:step=60
CDEF:offline=avg,UN,100,0,IF
CDEF:pcavail=offline,3600,TREND
LINE:pcavail#ff0000:Availability
```

This defines `avg` as the 1-min time series of ping data.  Note we use `step=60` to ensure we get the best resolution of data even in a smaller graph.  Then we define `offline` as 100 when the server is there, 0 when not.  Then, `pcavail` is a 1-hour sliding window average of this, which will in effect be the percentage of time during the previous hour during which the server was available.

**However**, there's a problem in that RRDTool will silently summarise the source data before you get your hands on it, if there are many data points to a pixel in the graph (this won't happen if doing a `fetch` of course).  To get around that, you'd need to have the `offline` CDEF done at store time -- IE, have a `COMPUTE` type DS that is  100 or 0 depending on if the `avg` DS is known.  Then, any averaging will preserve data (normal averaging omits the unknowns, or the `xff` setting makes the whole `cdp` unknown).

```
rrdtool create ...
DS:rtt:GAUGE:120:0:9999
DS:offline:COMPUTE:rtt,UN,100,0,IF

rrdtool graph ...
DEF:offline=server.rrd:offline:AVERAGE:step=3600
LINE:offline#ff0000:Availability
```

If you are able to modify your RRD, and do not need historical data, then use of a COMPUTE in this way will allow you to display your data in a 1-hour stepped graph as you wanted.

Comment: The compute DS was the missing link ;) Also the sliding window average is good enough for my needs. Thanx!